# Realizar un reload a un datatables

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript, angular-datatables

Buenas tardes, necesito saber de que manera puedo aplicarle un `reload` a un datatable en typescript con Angular 2,

```
options = {
  dom: "Bfrtip",
  ajax: (data, callback, settings) => {
    this.servicioUsuarios.getUsuarios().subscribe(data => {
      this.usuarioArray = data
      console.log(this.usuarioArray);
      callback({
        aaData: data
      })
    }, e => {
      this.notificaciones.notificacionError(e);
    });
  },
  columns: [
    { data: "id" },
    { data: "login" },
    {
      "render":
      function (data, type, row) {
        return (row.nombre + ' ' + row.primerApellido + ' ' + row.segundoApellido);
      }
    },
    { data: "correo" },
    { data: "fechaAlta" },
  ],
  select: true,
  rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) => {
    $('td', row).unbind('click');
    $('td', row).bind('click', () => {
      this.usuarioArray = data;
      // $('td', row).addClass('alert alert-success');
    });
    return row;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo hice yo.

Deberías usar, la opción ajax de esta forma:

```
ajax  : {
    url : 'api/endpoint/data', // URL de tu endpoint
    dataSrc : ''
},
```

Debes obtener un referencia a la tabla de esta forma:

```
@ViewChild(DataTableDirective) private dtElement;
```

O si tienes varias tablas:

```
@ViewChildren(DataTableDirective) private dtElements;
```

Una vez teniendo la referencia simplemente utiliza el método `ajax.reload()`:

```
private async reloadTable(){
    let dtIntance = await this.dtElement.dtInstance;
    dtInstance.ajax.reload()
}
```

Comment: Disculpa, la referencia es a la directiva o al componente?.  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective) private dtElement;

Comment: No encuentro directiva solo componente :/

Comment: La directiva DatatableDirective. la que usas en tu template, en la tabla: `<table datatable>...`

Comment: lo tengo asi            <sa-datatable id="example" [options]="options" paginationLength="true" tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"

Comment: supongo que te regires a esto #mdModal="bs-modal" pero en la tabla verdad?

Comment: El problema de esta librería es que no está integrada completamente para usarla al estilo "angular 2". No viene con un comoonente `DatatableComponent` o algo por el estilo con la funcionalidad del data binding,  inputs, event emmiters... La unica forma de acceder a la API de datatables es a través de dtInstance.

Comment: Si viene con el DatatablesComponent

Comment: Y de que manera puedo hacerlo, necesito tu ayuda :/, o que otro tipo de tabla puedo utlizar que no tenga tanto problema

Comment: podrías agregar el link de la librería (angular datatables) que estás utilizando? Igual me estoy confundiendo.

Comment: Yo me refiero a esta: https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/

Comment: Aquí tienes un ejemplo de uso: https://github.com/joseahr/sig-betera/blob/master/client/src/app/modules/admin/components/admin-layers/admin-layers.component.ts

Comment: Utiliza datatables?

Comment: Sí... Creía que estabas usando esa librería.